# Working with Android InputStreams in native c code

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, inputstream

Can anyone give me a hint how to work with Android InputStream in native code.

More specific example:
Java code

```
public class SomeParser {
    public native ArrayList<String> parse(InputStream stream);
}
```

I need to read InputStream in native and return matching patterns to Android Java code.
`stream` is BufferedInputStream from `HttpRequest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needd to pass a reference to the `Stream` through JNI to your native code, and then use JNI calls to act upon it. You will probably get java byte-arrays. These you can copy to native arrays using JNI. It is all standard JNI.

Comment: So it seems no way to work with Java InputStream as with C iostream?
Main idea that Java code (atm) fetching Http and gives to native code work with inputstream so it can be loaded into something like pugixml.

Comment: A java object is not an extension of a C++ `std::iostream`, or a C `FILE`*. There is no (statndard) way to convert these.  You will have to manipulate the Java object though the JNI interface from your native code. This is cumbersome and very error prone, compared to the native Java calls.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will pass ByteArray to native, at least 'till network communication will be on Java side.

Thanks!